# jQuery Ajax request every 30 seconds

Tags: jquery, ajax, yql

I have this piece of code, but the values may change while someone is on my site. I would need to update the #finance div every 30 seconds or so. Can this be done?

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON(
        "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22%5EFTSE%22)%0A%09%09&format=json&env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env&callback=?",

        function(json){
          $('#finance').text(json.query.results.quote.Change);
            // Patching payload into page element ID = "dog"
        });
});
```

Comment: Don't forget to pick an answer.  Please go back to some of the 50 or so questions you've asked and accept some answers on them, too.

Comment: Apologies. Will do. I'm all take at the moment lol

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can put your code in a separate function like this:

```
function LoadFinance()
{
    $(function() {
        $.getJSON(
        "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22%5EFTSE%22)%0A%09%09&format=json&env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env&callback=?",
        function(json){ $('#finance').text(json.query.results.quote.Change);
        // Patching payload into page element ID = "dog" 
        });
    });
}
```

And then set up a timer calling the function every 30 seconds:

```
setInterval( LoadFinance, 30000 );
```

Comment: Don't pass a string to `setInterval()`, use a direct reference! `setInterval(LoadFinance, 30000 );`

Comment: ouch .. `setInterval( LoadFinance, 30000 );` avoid text code that need to be evaluated.

Comment: You're right, a direct reference would be a nicer/cleaner approach. But my suggestion above doesn't compromise security...

Comment: @Alex - actually, it does.  *never* pass a string if you can avoid it.  I can override your function whenever I want the way you have it, any globally defined function works.  With a direct reference in it's own scope, it can't be overriden.  If you're using a string because of security...you have it backwards.

Comment: @Nick - Actually I normally use direct references when no parameters are required, why I chose a string in my suggestion above, was a "spur of the moment"-thing.. ;) But I see your point on security regarding the scope for the function. I'll keep it in mind. Thanks for the lesson!

Comment: That works a treat! Not really understanding the concept of "never pass a string"

Comment: @Model - there are other things wrong with this...for instance why wrap the internals of a function inside a `document.ready` to run the check every time?  Also, this doesn't fire immmediately, it waits 30 seconds before firing the first time.  For the string part: tThe previous answer before the edit was passing a string, click the edit link above...or see my answer below for how to do it more efficiently overall (e.g. checking `document.ready` once).

Comment: As of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11342199/how-to-load-a-part-of-page-every-30-secons), it should be known that using `setInterval` for this kind of case is a **very** bad idea.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine, I did. Now that I have read the documentation, it makes better sense (go figure: reading the documentation is helpful)! Removing my comment. Thanks.

Comment: @Thomas ah, my bad, I didn't see that in your comment. Glad you got it sorted out.

Answer (score 19):

You can set it on an interval, like this:

```
$(function() {
  function update() {
      $.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22%5EFTSE%22)%0A%09%09&format=json&env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env&callback=?", 
      function(json){
        $('#finance').text(json.query.results.quote.Change);  
    });
  }
  setInterval(update, 30000);
  update();
});
```

[`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) fires the first time *after* the interval (e.g. it first runs 30 seconds after the DOM loads here)... so for the that initial load, you still need to call it immediately as well via `update()`.

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely:

```
setInterval(      
  function() {
    $.getJSON(
      "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22%5EFTSE%22)%0A%09%09&format=json&env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env&callback=?",

    function(json){ $('#finance').text(json.query.results.quote.Change);
    // Patching payload into page element ID = "dog" });

  },
  30000);
```