# How to load a part of page every 30 seconds

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [jQuery Ajax request every 30 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450579/jquery-ajax-request-every-30-seconds)

I know we can load a part of page on some event. I also know we can load whole web page every specified time, but I wanted to know how to load a part of page every 30 seconds.

Comment: If you use AJAX you can can call AJAX method using `setInterval()` function. https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.setInterval

Comment: @antyrat using `setInterval` with AJAX is a **very** bad idea.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine so what's the good idea?

Comment: I dont want to use setinterval, as it unnecessary hit the server, even if there is no update. IS there any way so that once data is updated on server, it loads on my page.

Comment: You could look into long poll ajax calls, which are ajax calls that wait for a long time, then timeout, then reconnect for a long time again, then get data, then reconnect etc.

Comment: @SapnaAgrawal: You need to ask a new question for this. It is too different from your initial question. What you are looking for are WebSockets or COMET-style AJAX long polling.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
function refreshPage() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/test.html',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
            $('.result').html(data);
        },
        complete: function() {
            window.setTimeout(refreshPage, 30000);
        }
    });
}

window.setTimeout(refreshPage, 30000);
```

Using `setTimeout` has the advantage that if the connection hangs for some time you will not get tons of pending requests since a new one will only be sent after the previous one finished.

Comment: Dude there is no need of setTimeout second time

Comment: @Random of course there is. You're relaunching the next ajax call right away otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

```
function load_content(){

    setTimeout(function(){

        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax/example.html',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data) {
                $('.result').html(data);
                load_content();
            }
        });dataType: 'html',

    },30000);

}

load_content();
```

Comment: Using `setInterval` with AJAX is a **very** bad idea.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine How else would you do it?

Comment: `setTimeout` and create a new timeout after the previous request was successful or failed (i.e. in the `complete` callback)

Comment: @FlorianMargaine please elaborate

Comment: `setTimeout( function load() { $.ajax({ complete: function() { setTimeout( load, 30000 ); }) }, 30000 )`

Comment: @Jleagle your code is weird, but it does work :) Really weird tho.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Made more sense to me this way around, as you only use setTimeout() once :)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has already a build in functionality to replace a element's content by a remote file, called [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/). With [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) you can use this oneliner:

```
window.setTimeout($('#refresh').load('/remote/content.html'), 30000);
```

`#refresh` is the id of the element to refresh, `/remote/content.html` is the remote content.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(function() {
   setInterval(function() {
     getData();  // call to function
   }, 30000 );  // 30 seconds
});


// define your function here
function getData() {
   var url ="/mypage.php?type=load_data";
   var httpobj = $.ajax({url:url,async:false});  // send request
   var response = httpobj.responseText.trim(); //get response
   $('#myDiv').html(response);  // display data
}
```

Comment: Read the comments on all the other answers. Seriously.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using jQuery you can use the [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method

```
setInterval(function(){

    $('#some-kinda-container').load('/some/kinda/url.html #bit-you-need');

}, 30000);
```

Comment: See @Jleagle's answers' comments to see why it's a **very** bad idea to use `setInterval`.

Comment: if your ajax calls aren't completing in 30 seconds you have bigger things to worry about than setInterval

Comment: It's not about 30 seconds the first time, it's about remaining constant. If you need 2s to get the response, you'll overlap your requests in 5 minutes or so (didn't calculate, but you get the point)

Comment: There will only be overlap if the load() takes longer than 30 seconds surely?

Comment: No, there will be overlap after multiple requests, each one taking 2 seconds. 15 requests later, two requests will overlap each other.

Comment: Because `setInterval` doesn't wait for your request to finish. It will be run every 30 seconds, no matter what.

Comment: If you use SetTimeout then it will be 30 seconds plus 2 seconds fetch time so will definitely be out of sync and not what the op asked for, i don't understand your point i think, as setInterval will give you an ajax request after every x seconds no matter what the ajax delay, assuming the ajax delay is no longer than the interval there will be no overlap: http://jsfiddle.net/tDhGf/1/